# Fetch not found on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, git-fetch, google-breakpad

i am trying to use the breakpad, but got stuck at fetch cant be found.. i am trying to install fetch from Ubuntu repositories, but there also fetch is not available.

Any suggestions.

Version
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

```
administrator@ESC-UBUNTU:~$ cd $WORKINGDIR
administrator@ESC-UBUNTU:~$ git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
fatal: destination path 'depot_tools' already exists and is not an empty directory.
administrator@ESC-UBUNTU:~$ export PATH=$PATH:$WORKINGDIR/depot_tools
administrator@ESC-UBUNTU:~$ cd depot_tools
administrator@ESC-UBUNTU:~/depot_tools$ mkdir breakpad && cd breakpad
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘breakpad’: File exists
administrator@ESC-UBUNTU:~/depot_tools$ fetch breakpad

Command 'fetch' not found, did you mean:

  command 'sfetch' from deb biosquid (1.9g+cvs20050121-11)
  command 'afetch' from deb biosquid (1.9g+cvs20050121-11)
  command 'efetch' from deb acedb-other (4.9.39+dfsg.02-4build1)
  command 'efetch' from deb ncbi-entrez-direct (12.0.20190816+ds-1)
  command 'ifetch' from deb ifetch-tools (0.17.2-2)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

administrator@ESC-UBUNTU:~/depot_tools$ cd src
-bash: cd: src: No such file or directory
administrator@ESC-UBUNTU:~/depot_tools$ ./configure
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
administrator@ESC-UBUNTU:~/depot_tools$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
administrator@ESC-UBUNTU:~/depot_tools$ cd
```

Comment: Please run `$ echo $WORKINGDIR` and show us the result of it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that `$WORKINGDIR` is empty. That's why `cd $WORKINGDIR` enters your home directory as it is the same as `cd`.

If this suggestion is correct, this means, that you are adding a relative path to your `PATH`, which won't work. You need to add the full path to `depot_tools` in your `PATH`.